# How to handle windows authentication popup in Robot Framework RIDE?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

Windows authentication popup of my application appears similar to this app https://www.engprod-charter.net/ I had used below code to handle window authentication popup in selenium using python.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import win32com.client

driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.engprod-charter.net/')
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")   
shell.Sendkeys("username")  
shell.Sendkeys("{TAB}")
shell.Sendkeys("password@123") 
time.sleep(5)
shell.Sendkeys("{ENTER}")
time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```

But since I am using python 2.7.12 for Robot Framework, it seems win32com.client is not supported there. I want to know what library I have to use in Robot Framework to handle this scenario.

I am not asking complete solution as this is not the correct approach in stackoverflow, just want a hint what should I try to handle my scenario. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve your scenario using [AutoItLibrary](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/AutoItLibrary/1.1.post1)  which handles window inputs and similar things. Basically controlling the entire GUI not just the browser.

First install AutoItLibrary for Robot Framework

1. Make sure you have python installed for 32 bit(say python 2.7.6)
2. Install pywin32-217.win32-py2.7.exe for 32 bit from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20217/)
3. Download [AutoItLibrary](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/AutoItLibrary/1.1.post1) and unzip the folder
4. Open command prompt as Administrator and go to downloaded AautoItLibrary folder folder(cd...\AutoItLibrary-1.1.post1) and then write this command and hit enter  **python setup.py install**

Now include AutoItLibrary in Robot Framework
[image]
Let us know if this works, I would be interested to know

Comment: Did you find anything @ShoaibAkhtar ? :)

Comment: No success yet. I have used AutoIt with Java but still not able to get how to use AutoIt in Robot Framework as I am new to Robot Framework

Comment: Yes, the only consistent workaround is to use AutoItLibrary with custom firefox profile. 
`1. First create your own firefox profile (google how to create). 
2. Then launch firefox with the new profile created, and launch the <url> you want to test.
3. When the authorization alert come out, manually input the username & password and click enter or proceed.  This will save the username & password to this browser cache/cookie.. 
4. Next, on RIDE -> 
Open Browser <url> firefox ff_profile_dir=${your_new_profile_dir}
Sleep 2s 
AutoItLibrary.Send {ENTER}`

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using Robot Class in java, which can be run in Robotframework test when required.

i.e. A .jar which will function as handler for the windows authentication pop up.

In RobotFramework you would just need to run a .jar which will handle your pop up.

Just in case you are not used to Java, I can help you with a sample code.

Comment: I am aware of Robot class in case of Java. But currently I am working on Robot Framework and python, so wanted to know how to handle windows authentication there

Comment: doesn't look like there is a simpler way in python! so why not use the simple method from Java and make it callable from RobotFramework or Python (basically from command line). Its your choice though!