# How to implement Automation for Drag and drop between two file explorers on Windows

Tags: automation, drag-and-drop, robotframework, autoit

I am trying to automate drag and drop between two File Explorers on windows OS. I could find online help to drag and drop implementation for Browsers. 
But no help for drag and drop for file to another File Explorer.

Comment: Please see my answer on `Autoit` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035353/how-to-handle-windows-authentication-popup-in-robot-framework-ride/41035644#41035644

Comment: @Goralight Using autoit Im not able to implement drag and drop. And your solution is from browser. what can be done for File Explorer?

Comment: Have you looked at `Mouse Down`, `Mouse Move` and `Mouse Down`? But either way, this is kinda made for Browser / Web stuff. But I don't think this will stop you with File Browser to File Browser as AutoIt talks to the desktop anyway... Have you tried anything or?

Comment: Actually we can do it in static environment. For ex if you want to drag a file from source folder, with mouse drag, you need to give x and y co-ordinates. But this x and y coordinates are highly likely changing in dynamic enviroment

Answer (score 0):

Use for this the Shell.Application object. To get the selection from the explorer you can use the following function:

```
;===============================================================================
; Function Name....: _ActiveExplorer_GetSelected
; Description......: Creates an array with
;                    - Count of selected files/folder
;                    - Path of active Explorer window and
;                    - the path/es of selected file/s /folder
; Requirement(s)...: Opened Explorer window
; Return Value(s)..: Array with data, $a[0] = Count, $a[1] = Folderpath, $a[2..] = File/Foldername
; .................: ATTENTION! Last index $a[0]+1 !!
; Author(s)........: BugFix ( AutoIt@bug-fix.info )
;===============================================================================
Func _ActiveExplorer_GetSelected()
    Local $oShell = ObjCreate("Shell.Application")
    Local $oExplorer, $sPath, $oFolderView, $iCount = 0, $sSelectedFiles = '', $n = 2
    Local $oShellWindows = $oShell.Windows
    For $i = 0 To $oShellWindows.Count -1
        $oExplorer = $oShellWindows($i)
        $sPath = StringReplace(StringReplace(StringTrimLeft($oExplorer.LocationURL, 8), '%20', ' '), '/', '\')
        If WinGetTitle('[ACTIVE]') = $sPath Then ExitLoop
    Next
    $oFolderView = $oExplorer.Document.SelectedItems()
    $iCount = $oFolderView.Count
    Local $aOut[$iCount +2]
    $aOut[0] = $iCount
    $aOut[1] = $sPath
    If $iCount = 0 Then
        Return ''
    Else
        For $oFolderItem In $oFolderView
            $aOut[$n] = $oFolderItem.Name
            $n += 1
        Next
        Return $aOut
    EndIf
EndFunc  ; ==>_ActiveExplorer_GetSelected
```

Comment: Okay ..Thanks @McBarby  ill try for it. And let you know