# SecureAuth Sign in Popup - ROBOT Framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, basic-authentication

Hi Robot Framework experts.

Using Robot Framework I had automated a portal which uses secureAuth for sign in and I'm able to execute the tests in local desktop no Single sign on issue as I'm already signed into company portal, so scripts automatically sign into the application.

But I have to run these tests in a remote server and when the script clicks on Login in button Secureauth displays a pop up as seen in the attached screenshot. I am unable to enter text in the pop up or do anything with script.

Tried:

Sending ID and password in URL( https://ID:Password@uri ) did not work.
Tried Alert keywords did not work. I guess it is not a alert at all.
Can someone point me in right direction Please.

Thank you for your time…[Login screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngu92.png)

Comment: how did you use Alert? can you share w/ some code?

Comment: Here they say `Sending ID and password in URL( https://ID:Password@uri )` don't work in IE. Maybe you can try other browser. Seems tricky. Many similar questions on the forum. https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters


Here is some guys recommending to try AutiItLibrary. Maybe you can try? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035353/how-to-handle-windows-authentication-popup-in-robot-framework-ride

Comment: Finally, i am able to solve this by using the browser library in Robot Framework. only down side is I had to replace all selenium keywords as browser Library is based on Playwright, it has it own keywords to handle browser events.

Comment: @RaviG can you please share the solution ? thanks